# use a asp textbox in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I want to use a JavaScript in backend and I want to call a textbox in this function
A example of the code is this

html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbOrigen" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

asp.net

```
Dim event As String
event = "function showMensage() {document.getElementById('<%= tbOrigen.ClientID %>').value='Hola';}
```

This is the code that I find in internet, but don't works, anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: Look up in google: `ClientScript.RegisterScriptBlock`

Comment: Thanks, but ClientScript.RegisterScripBlock is in front-end, and I want to execute the script in back-end.

Comment: You can run javascript in the backend, it's a front-end technology. The best is use Client.RegisterScriptBlock which runs your script when page is reloaded (after postback). It injects the script you create in the backend into the page after postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Id you are using in your scriptlet is incorrect

Should look like this:

```
event = "function showMensage() {document.getElementById('<%= tbOrigen.ClientID %>').value='Hola';}
```

Comment: Sorry I changed tbOrigen to textBox, in the question, but in the code was like you write. Then, I have the same problem :S

Comment: Then I would look into what codingbiz suggested with ClientScript.RegisterScriptBlock